# class structure for representing a workflow

Tags: java, linked-list, uml, workflow, sequence

What is the best way to represent a workflow in a Java-class structure (workflow is regarded as a sequence of actions)? Lets assume a class Workflow contains Action-objects. I thought that would be possible by using a LinkedList, but then no branching could be done.

My aim is to represent a structure that is similar to UML activity diagrams, which means that it should also be possible to define desicions, splits and joins.

Another soultion would be to use a LinkedList of BuildingBlocks, which defines an interface. Then additional classes are created to define Desicions and Splits or Joins implementing this interface (splits and joins may be represented as one container holding further LinkedLists with BuildingBlocks)

What do you think about this idea or do you know better solutions?

If you know further "keywords" i could use for a google-search concerning this topic, please don't hesitate to post them!

Comment: Hmm ... searching for "java workflow engine" yielded a lot of results.

Answer (score 3):

I'd recommend to take a look at the class hierarchy used by Microsoft in their implementation of [Windows Workflow Foundation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd489441%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) platform (instead of completely reinventing a wheel)

The source code is open for inspection, see e.g. http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Activities/System/Activities/Statements/FlowSwitch.cs

They have already thought about the [Workflow Designer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc835242.aspx) with the graphical language etc.

The Workflow Foundation platform is not readily available outside the Windows Operating System as said in the status of the [corresponding Mono project](http://www.mono-project.com/Workflow)

So if your target OS is Windows then you can just use .NET. If your target platform is non-Windows then you can at least take a look. C# and Java are copy/paste friendly languages.

Answer (score 1):

I would use some sort of `strategy` pattern with some abstraction that represents `Hops`.

```
interface Hop{
 List<Hop> backwardHops();
 List<Hop> forwardHops();
}

abstract class AbstractHop implements Hop{
 private String name;
 public String getName(){
 return this.name;
 }
} 

class ConcreteHop extends AbstractHop{
  // method implementations
  // to return the available backward and forward hops from this hop 
}

class MyObjectWithCurrentFlow {
 private AbstractHop currentHop;
 // the initial hop or current workflow
 MyObjectWithCurrentFlow(AbstractHop currentHop){
 this.currentHop = currentHop;
 }
 // strategy pattern goes here
 void pushItBackwardOrForward(AbstractHop newHop){
   // check if this hop is a valid hop
   this.currentHop = newHop;
 }
}
```